# Multinomial coefficients modulo a prime

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime and let $m \geq 1$. Lucas' theorem implies that the binomial coefficient ${p^m-1 \choose k}$ is not divisible by $p$ for any $0 \leq k \leq p^m-1$. I wonder if something similar holds for multinomial coefficients ${p^m-1 \choose k_1, \ldots, k_s}$ where $k_1, \ldots, k_s$ are non-negative integers such that $k_1 + \cdots + k_s = p^m-1$. That is, what are sufficient and necessary conditions for such multinomial coefficients to not be divisible by $p$? Thanks!

Comment: Do you wish to provide stricter constraints on $s$ or $k_i$?  When $m>1$ we have if $k_i=1$ for all $i$, the coefficient becomes simply $(p^m-1)!$ which is clearly divisible by $p$.  Similarly, if $k_i<p$ for all $i$, we can easily guarantee that it will be divisible by $p$ since there are factors of $p$ in the numerator and none in the denominator.

Comment: Yes thanks for noticing that. There should definitely be some constraints. I wonder what may be sufficient and or necessary conditions on the parameters.

Comment: Partial solution: How many times will $p$ be a factor of the numerator when writing this as a ratio of products of factorials?  I.e. what is the largest $k$ such that $p^k\mid (p^m-1)!$ (*how many multiples of $p$?  of $p^2$? of $p^3$?...*).  In what scenarios will the denominator have or not have a combined total of $k$ times that $p$ divides into? (*note: it can never be more than $k$ since the multinomial coefficient is always an integer.  when then can it be less than $k$?  equal to $k$?*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lucas' Theorem generalizes to multinomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80169/reference-needed-for-lucas-theorem-for-multinomial-coefficients-modulo-a-prime): if
$\displaystyle
k_n=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_{n,i}p^i,
$
with $a_{n,i}\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$, then
$$
{p^m-1\choose k_1,\ldots,k_s}\equiv {p-1\choose a_{1,0},\ldots,a_{s,0}}\cdots{p-1\choose a_{1,m-1},\ldots,a_{s,m-1}}\mod p.
$$
The $p-1$'s that occur on the right hand side are from the base-$p$ representation of $p^m-1$.
It follows that ${p^m-1\choose k_1,\ldots,k_s}$ is not divisible by $p$ if and only if there are no "carries" when the sum $k_1+\ldots+k_s$ is computed in base $p$.